# Add a UILabel in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uilabel

I have a tableView which displays a list of songs, when i tap on any one it gets played.

```
-(void) PlaySelectedSong:(id) sender{       
Song *aSong=[aCategory.Items objectAtIndex:appDelegate.selectedSong];
NSString *content1=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://192.168.50.108:8888/%@",[aSong.Link stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];

NSLog(content1);
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:content1];

NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
webView.delegate=self;
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

}

This is how it get played.
The problem is that while playing it is showing the URL of the song. i am planning to add a label above it. so that i can set the label text to the song name.

How do i add a label to do the same. Any one knows.? Need Help.

Thanks,
Shibin

Comment: Please post the code for the UI when the song is playing.

Comment: what is aSong.Link's contents, post out the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really need more information to answer the question but it sounds like you want to have two text fields in your table view.

When creating the `UITableViewCell` create it using the `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` style.

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                               reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

You can then specify a subtitle in the cell that will be displayed using

```
cell.textLabel.text = songTitle;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = songUrl;
```